# Cannot open Expo Go on ios 11.4 simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, simulator, expo-go

Folks.

I have a problem developing my first react native app with expo. I'm using Xcode simulator to test it on ipad. It works fine on iPad 6 simulator with iOS 15.0, instead on iPad 6 simulator with iOS 11.4 when I click the Expo Go icon on simulator to open the app, it opens and closes immediately without running the app on simulator.
Does anyone know something about it?

Thanks.

`XCode Simulator Version: 13.1 (970)`

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-av": "~10.1.3",
    "expo-device": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
```

Comment: Hi Dima, seems like the context you provided in your question is not enough to answer it. Please provide more information about your issue.

Comment: Hi, @YamanKATBY. Thanks for your answer. Check out my changes, hope it's more clear now than it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so u using expo 43 SDK this is reason why

iOS 15 is fully supported; iOS 11 support has been dropped.
With the release of iOS 15, we have dropped support for iOS 11 in the Expo SDK. SDK 43 supports iOS 12 and higher.

source - https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-43-aa9b3c7d5541